# tkinter,save file workbook using openpyxl by asksaveasfile

Tags: python, tkinter, openpyxl

I wanted to create new excel file using tkinter asksaveasfile dialog box. The very known mechanism to create new excel file using openpyxl is the following. I want to use it with asksaveasfile tkinter module.

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
foo = Workbook()
foo.active()
foo.save("C:\\Users\\Dave\\Documents\\foo.xlxs")
```

Comment: What's the actual question?

Comment: Thank you sir, I already figured it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was

```
import openpyxl
from tkinter.filedialog import askdirectory

download_Directory = askdirectory(title="Select Folder Downloading Folder")
scheduler_form = Workbook()
scheduler_form.active
path = download_Directory+"\\scheduler_form.xlsx"
scheduler_form.save(path)
```